# Get whether a key is currently pressed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to check whether a given key is currently pressed in JavaScript.
So far I have this:

```
var keys = new Map();
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    keys.set(e.keyCode, true);
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    keys.delete(e.keyCode);
});
```

This works fine, except that keys can get stuck whenever they're unpressed when the window isn't focused, or for whatever other reason the keyup event doesn't fire. Is there a way check whether a key is pressed with 100% accuracy?

Comment: add an event for [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event) or beforeunload etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `unload`? The event developers should [avoid using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event#usage_notes)? Why does that help here?

Comment: @evolutionxbox or beforeunload etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm still a bit confused as to why that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a blur event to the window to clear the keys, because if the window is not in focus it can't register any events.

https://jsfiddle.net/tpakswqh/1/

```
window.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  keys.clear();
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but there are still some things that prevent the events from firing like right clicking, and I'd rather not go through and add every edge case if it can be avoided.

Comment: You wont get the keyup events in the edge cases, so you can't react to them. Another way would be to check the keyboard status in a while loop, but I don't think it's possible in javascript.